# About the api setRotationFromEuler of Object3D

Tags: three.js

1、 I declare a euler by following code

```
const a = new THREE.Euler(
  -3.141_592_653_589_793,
  3.437_327_006_328_146_7,
  -3.141_592_653_589_793,
  'XYZ',
)
```

2、And then, i apply this euler to a Object3D

```
const group = new THREE.Object3D()
group.setRotationFromEuler(a)
```

3、when i see the rotation setting value of this object

```
console.log(group.rotation)
```

it output as following:

```
{
    "isEuler": true,
    "_x": 1.2246467991473532e-16,
    "_y": 0.2060735069487366,
    "_z": 1.2246467991473532e-16,
    "_order": "XYZ"
}
```

the value seems strange, how it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Object3D in three.js stores its rotation in two ways — as a quaternion, and as Euler angles — and keeps them in sync. `group.setRotationFromEuler(...)` is equivalent to:

```js
group.quaternion.setFromEuler( euler );
```

This sets the quaternion to a rotation equivalent to the given Euler, and then updates the Euler associated with the object. Because there is more than one way to represent the same orientation as an Euler, you may not see the same numbers in your console, but the orientation is the same.

If you prefer to manage the Euler directly, do this instead:

```js
group.rotation.set( x, y, z, 'XYZ' );
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, would please check my another question, the url is 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350319/what-is-the-correct-direction-of-ratation-in-threejs