# What is the correct direction of rotation in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js uses the right handed system and this means counter clockwise is default rotation. for example,

```
group.rotation.y += Math.PI / 6
```

it will rotate the group in counter clockwise by 30°

[image]

But if I update rotation beforehand as following

```
group.rotation.set(Math.PI, 0, Math.PI, 'XYZ')
```

and then execute the same rotation again,

```
group.rotation.y += Math.PI / 6
```

it seems the direction of rotation changes to be clockwise;

why does it happen, how can I know the direction exactly
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide a detailed answer. Just to exclude issues where the 3D asset (internal geometry) would be in a different coordinate space, can you test with a plain cube first (or a cone/arrow/axesHelper/etc.) ? Hope this tip helps isolate the issue. Good luck

Comment: @George, please see this project: https://codesandbox.io/s/tou-zi-forked-q3xzkw, i add a plain cube, it also has the same problem;

Comment: Set it to `cube.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI, "XYZ");` and you will see that the axis of rotation changed. That's just how euler angles work. You have to use quaternions if you want absolute rotation values. Or you can wrap your cube with a group